# server.listen не работает

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express, веб-сервер

У меня есть express приложение, которое запускается через модуль http:

```
  try {
    await client.connect();

    server.listen(PORT);
    server.on('error', onError);
    server.on('listening', onListening);

    console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`);

  } catch (e) {
    console.log('Database connect error!');
    console.log(e);

  } finally {
    await client.close();   }
```

И запуск происходит без ошибок, в консоль выводится:

> Server started on port 3000

Но вместо запуска страницы у меня висит вечная загрузка. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Какой страницы?

Comment: Таки server.listen работает. Иначе была бы не вечная загрузка, а ошибка соединения. А причины вечной загрузки нужно искать у вас в коде.

Comment: @AlexeyTen а в чем же может быть ошибка, например?

Comment: В чём угодно. Самое очевидное, вы забыли вернут ь ответ. В общем надо смотреть код, который вы не показали